# FQL returns 400 Error on application but works well on browser and API Explorer

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

The following FQL query works when i paste it on my browser and also works in the API explorer (xxxx is replaced with numbers as well as access token)

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT page_id from place WHERE (distance(latitude, longitude,"xxxxx","xxxxx") < xxxx)&access_token=<MY ACCESS TOKEN>
```

When i run the same code from my java application i get an HTTP 400 Error. Any idea what's causing this?

This following code implements the connection. getInputStream() throws an exception (Error 400)

```
connection = (URLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
input = connection.getInputStream();
```

Comment: show how you initialize the `url` variable

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to URLEncode the "q" parameter value ?
Something like :

```
String query = SELECT page_id from place WHERE (distance(latitude, longitude,"xxxxx","xxxxx") < xxxx)&access_token=<MY ACCESS TOKEN>;
String urlString = "https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=" + URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8"));
connection = (URLConnection) new URL(urlString ).openConnection();
input = connection.getInputStream();
```